# ImportError: No module named defs

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, importerror

I am new to programming and I'm trying to run a code following the provided described steps. from the first command `python main.py -f [fastafile]` I'm encountering this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pretest import get_pretest_dict, prepare_test_dict
  File "/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/pretest/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from get_bmp51_pretest import get_pretest_dict
  File "/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/pretest/get_bmp51_pretest.py", line 10, in <module>
    from defs import INPUT_DIR
ImportError: No module named defs
```

Please, could anyone help me to fix this error??

Comment: Whats should be in defs ? or whats INPUT_DIR?

Answer (score 0):

You need a file called `defs.py` in the same directory than `get_bmp51_pretest.py`. I'm assuming that somewhere in the README they tell you to create that file, and to stick config values in it, *a la Django*. E.g. of `def.py`:

```
INPUT_DIR = "/home/islem/MyInputFastas"
```

Comment: the pah was set in defs.py but I still encountering an error (not the same one)

Comment: yup thanks, but I still encoutering an error.
the message is too long, I cant post here